# ValueError: I/O operation on closed file (File shouldn't be closed)

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, while-loop

I'm trying to create a program that generates a random series of math symbols (+, -, etc) and a variable and then writes it to a file, afterwards testing each math operation to see how well it can solve a math problem - scoring it based on its performance doing so and then mutating up to 5 'child' files off of it.

When trying to run the following code, it can run through the while loop just fine the first time, but every time after it won't work and throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python Files\Evolving\mEvolve.py", line 97, in <module>
    sList.append(scoreFile(f, lFile))
  File "C:\Python Files\Evolving\mEvolve.py", line 22, in scoreFile
    file.seek(0)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

This is the code I am trying to run:

```
# Main code
lFile = open('eLog.txt', mode='w') # Log file for logging events
bFile = open('ops.txt', mode='w+') # Starting 'parent' file to modify
lFile.write("Started evolution. New file 'ops.txt' created.")
r = pseudoRandom(1, 5) 
for i in range(r): # Write a random amount of data to file
    bFile.write(genAtom())
lFile.write("\nWrote %d characters into file 'ops.txt' to start." % r)

while True:
    sList = [] # Empty the temporary score list
    for i in range(pseudoRandom(1, 5)): # Generate between 1 and 5 'mutated' files.
        genCount = genCount + 1
        bFile.seek(0)
        fContent = list(bFile.read()) # Get parent file content
        nContent = mutate(fContent, lFile, pseudoRandom(1, 5)) # Mutate file content
        fName = "ops[%d].txt" % genCount
        nFile = open(fName, mode='w+') # Open new 'child' file
        nFile.write(''.join(nContent)) # and write mutated content to it
        fList.append(nFile)
    bFile.close() # Close old parent file
    remove(bFile.name) # and remove it
    for f in fList: # Score all child files
        sList.append(scoreFile(f, lFile)) # <-- Error occurs here
    bFile = fList[sList.index(min(sList))] # Choose new best file based on scores
    lFile.write("\nScored %d files. Best score %d." % (len(sList), min(sList)))
    scoreList.append(min(sList))
    del fList[sList.index(min(sList))] # Remove best scoring child file from fList
    for f in fList: # and delete all other child files
        f.close()
        remove(f.name)
    c = input("Finished, loop again? (Leave blank for yes or n for no): ")
    if c.lower() == 'n':
        break
```

and the relevant scoreFile function:

```
def scoreFile(file, log): # Score provided file
    optPos = 0
    curPos = 10
    s = 1
    file.seek(0)
    fileList = list(file.read())
    fileRes = ' '.join(str(e) for e in fileList) # Translate file data
    try: # and test to see if its contents can solve a problem
        scr = abs(optPos-eval("curPos = curPos %s" % fileRes))
    except: # Give it terrible score if it doesn't make sense
        scr = 1000
    log.write("\nFile '%s' scored %d." % (file.name, scr))
    return scr
```

Mutate function:

```
def mutate(fileCont, log, lCount): # Mutate the file provided
    for i in range(lCount): # a certain amount of times
        try:
            actionLoc = pseudoRandom(0, len(fileCont)-1) # Pick a random part of file content to mess with
        except: # File content was under two characters (results in asking for between 0 and 0)
            actionLoc = 0 # so just set it to 0
        action = pseudoRandom(0, 2)
        if action == 0: # Replace
            newItem = genAtom() # Generate new 'atom' of code to replace with
            try:
                fileCont[actionLoc] = newItem
                log.write("\nMutated: Replaced atom %d." % actionLoc)
            except: # Chosen content doesn't exist (file was likely empty)
                fileCont.insert(actionLoc, newItem)
                log.write("\nMutated: Attempted atom replacement failed;")
                log.write("\ninserted new random atom instead for atom %d." % actionLoc)
        elif action == 1: # Delete
            try:
                del fileCont[actionLoc]
                log.write("\nMutated: Deleted atom %d." % actionLoc)
            except: # Chosen content doesn't exist (file was likely empty)
                newItem = genAtom()
                fileCont.insert(actionLoc, newItem)
                log.write("\nMutated: Attempted atom deletion failed;")
                log.write("\ninserted new random atom instead for atom %d." % actionLoc)
        else: # Duplicate
            try: # Take the content and insert a duplicate
                newItem = fileCont[actionLoc]
                fileCont.insert(actionLoc, newItem)
                log.write("\nMutated: Duplicated atom %d." % actionLoc)
            except: # Chosen content doesn't exist (file was likely empty)
                newItem = genAtom()
                fileCont.insert(actionLoc, newItem)
                log.write("\nMutated: Attempted atom duplication failed;")
                log.write("\ninserted new random atom instead for atom %d." % actionLoc)
    return fileCont
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **do** close files:

```
for f in fList: # and delete all other child files
    f.close()
    remove(f.name)
```

so in the next iteration of your `while` loop you pass in:

```
for f in fList: # Score all child files
    sList.append(scoreFile(f, lFile))
```

and `f` is a closed file.

`remove(f.name)` does *not* remove the file object from `fList`. You clear `sList`, but `fList` is retained between loop iterations.